# Замена блоков при нажатии кнопки

Tags: javascript, php

Нужно что бы после нажатии на кнопку убирался 1 блок,и заменялся на другие. К примеру:

Введите ваше имя
человек нажимает на кнопку и у него вместо введите ваше имя появляется

Введите ваш Адрес
Введите ваше Отчество

а само введите ваше имя убирается

Comment: Нет он ввел данные,нажал на кнопку и поменялся блок

Comment: Сами данные запоминаться не будут. На деле не важно зачем это мне) Нужно просто сделать это)

Answer (score 4):

так и сделайте, скрыли блок - показали блок

```js
let b = document.getElementById('next');
var actions = document.querySelectorAll('.action');


b.addEventListener('click', function(){
   let idx = this.dataset.idx || 0;
   actions[idx].classList.remove('active');
   if(++idx < actions.length){
       actions[idx].classList.add('active');
       this.dataset.idx = idx;
   }
});
```

```css
.action {
  display: none;
}
.action.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="action active">
     введите ваше имя
   </div>
   <div class="action">
     введите вашу фамилию
   </div>
   <div class="action">
     введите ваше отчество
   </div>
   <div class="action">
     введите ваше дату рождения
   </div>
   <div class="action">
     введите еще что-нибудь
   </div>
</div>

<button id="next">далее</button>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol: вот галерейка подъехала - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1243742/265406 Только там не оформлен вопрос, от слова "совсем".

Comment: @Sevastopol: я спать - у меня 4:35 ))) Zzz